# Optimizing simple query that performs a large table migration

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, optimization

There are two tables `trains` and `train_statuses`.
`train_statuses` already has a column `train_status` which is an ENUM.

```sql
CREATE TYPE train_status AS ENUM('queued', 'running', 'succeeded', 'failed', 'cancelled');
```

As part of the migration, I will be adding a new column `status` in trains table and updating it with only the final status from `train_statuses`. The final statuses are: 'succeeded', 'failed', 'cancelled'.

Other relevant details about the tables:

```
Indexes:
Trains table:
    "trains_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
     "idx_trains_queued_at" btree (queued_at DESC)

Train statuses table:
    "train_statuses_id_updated_at_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (id, updated_at)
    "idx_train_statuses_id_updated_at" btree (id, updated_at)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "train_statuses_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES trains(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This is the query that I am planning on using to update `status` in `trains` table.

```sql
UPDATE trains AS t SET status = (
    SELECT status FROM train_statuses ts 
    WHERE ts.id = t.id AND status in (?) 
    ORDER BY ts.updated_at DESC LIMIT 1
) WHERE ID in (
    SELECT id FROM trains LIMIT 100
)
```

I would be calling this query in a `for` loop until I get the number of rows affected as zero.
Even though this is a simple migration, the table involved is extremely huge and occupies ~150GB on production. Please review this query and suggest any possible optimizations that could be done taking into consideration the size of the table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An UPDATE with a co-related subquery is typically quite slow, because the sub-query is run once for each row that is updated. It's typically faster to do that only once. To get the latest status for each train, you can use DISTINCT ON and join to the result of that:

```
update trains t
  set status = ts.status
from (  
  SELECT distinct on (ts.id) ts.id, ts.status 
  FROM train_statuses ts 
  WHERE status in (?) 
  ORDER BY ts.id, updated_at DESC 
) 
WHERE t.id = ts.id;
```

Comment: "An UPDATE with a co-related subquery is typically quite slow", but I need to run the query in batches. I used the subquery so that I could use LIMIT on it.

Comment: yeah using DISTINCT makes sense, will make use of that, thanks.
But the sub-query to fetch the task_id, is there a avoid that?

Comment: Running a single UPDATE in batches is more often than not, slower than updating all rows in one large transaction. But you can always limit the rows the derived table (sub-query) returns.